# how can i get list of webpages(sitemap) with php?

Tags: php, sitemap

I need to get limited list of all pages, that belongs to some website Php. How would code look like? Limited means function(some url, limit of page).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this. Some web sites publish an [XML sitemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) and link to it from robots.txt, but most do not.

You may be able to assemble a partial list of pages on a site by crawling the site, e.g. requesting one page on the site, searching for links to other pages, and requesting those pages as well. However, this is not guaranteed to find all pages on a site -- some may not be reachable from the home page! -- and is a complex process.